# shnsplit failing to split multiple .flac files

Tags: audio-recording, flac, audio-player

I am on Xubuntu 17.10 trying to split a .flac album file into tracks. When running the command

```
shnsplit -f "Master Of Puppets.cue" -o "flac flac -s -o %f -" "Side A.flac"
```

shnplit responds with:

`shnsplit: warning: discarding initial zero-valued split point
shnsplit: error: split point 0 is not greater than previous split point 215871264`

My cue sheet has more than one file in the album, and the second file starting with a split point of 0 is not being accepted.

My .cue file: https://pastebin.com/22T79tqP

Answer (score 0):

Try to open `cue` file and split it into 2 `cue` files with the same header.
Then `shnsplit side1.flac vs side1.cue` and `side2.flac` vs `side2.cue` accordingly.